# Shared Object Not saving the level Progress

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, savegame

I am making a flash game in which i have a variable **levelState** that describes the current level in which user has entered I am using **SharedObject** to save the progress
but it does not do so 
first i declred a clas level variable

```
private var levelState:Number = 1;
private var mySaveData:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("levelSave");
```

in the Main function i am checking if it is a first run of the game like below

```
if (mySaveData.data.levelsComplete == null)
    {
        mySaveData.data.levelsComplete = 1;
    }
```

and in a function where the winning condition is checked so that levelState could be increased i am usin this sharedobject to hold the value of levelState

```
if (/*winniing condition*/)
    levelState++;
    mySaveData.data.levelsComplete = levelState;
    mySaveData.flush();
    setNewLevel(levelState);
}
```

but when i play the game clear a level and again run the game it does not start from that level it starts from beginning.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**
Actually in the main function i have to assign the **levelState** the value from the ShredObject . In the first part of the above code i added some lines like this

```
if (mySaveData.data.levelsComplete == null)
{
    mySaveData.data.levelsComplete = 1;
} else {
   levelState = mySaveData.data.levelsComplete
}
```

That **else part** i was missing